# Formula obtained by repeated integration by parts.

Tags: calculus, integration-by-parts

Tonight I was messing with the integration by parts formula and found the following formula. Starting with the usual $$\int udv = uv - \int vdu$$ and letting $u = f(x)$, $du = f'(x)dx$, $dv =dx$ and $v=x$ we obtain $$\int f(x)dx = xf(x) - \int xf'(x).$$ We then apply the apply the integration by parts formula again to the integral on the RHS to obtain $$\int f(x)dx = xf(x) - \frac{f'(x)x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int x^2f''(x)dx$$ and again:
$$\int f(x)dx = xf(x) - \frac{f'(x)x^2}{2} + \frac{f''(x)x^3}{2\cdot 3} - \frac{1}{2\cdot 3}\int x^3f'''(x)dx$$ So, in general, it seems (at least to me) safe to say that $$\int f(x) dx = xf(x) - \frac{f'(x)x^2}{2} + \frac{f''(x)x^3}{2\cdot 3} - \frac{f'''(x)x^4}{2\cdot 3\cdot 4} + \ldots =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^nf^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(-1)^{n+1}$$
Next, applying the alternating series estimation theorem, we have that $$|E_N|=\left|\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^nf^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(-1)^{n+1}\right) - \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{x^nf^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(-1)^{n+1}\right)\right| \leq \frac{x^{(N+1)}f^{(N+1)}(x)}{(N+1)!}(-1)^{N+1}$$ I then tried to use this estimate to approximate $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$. That is, since we have $$E_N \geq -\frac{x^{(N+1)}f^{(N+1)}(x)}{(N+1)!}(-1)^{N+1}$$ we can conclude that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx \approx \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{x^nf^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(-1)^{n+1}\right)-\frac{x^{(N+1)}f^{(N+1)}(x)}{(N+1)!}(-1)^{N+1}.$$

It then occured to me that to use the alternating series estimation theorem we must have that $$0\leq\frac{x^{n+1}f^{(n+1)}(x)}{(n+1)!}\leq \frac{x^{n}f^{(n)}(x)}{(n)!}$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^nf^{(n)}(x)}{n!} = 0$$ So it seems that the above approximation only works if we choose an $f(x)$ so that the above hypothesis are satisfied. **Is there a way to estimate the infinite sum that does not rely on the alternating series test so we do not have to worry about satisfying the above restrictions?**

More generally, I am interested if there is a more interesting route to take with this process of repeated integration by parts. The form of the terms in the infinite series remind me of taylor series. Is there a connection?

Comment: Strongly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141794/infinite-integration-by-parts

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration . And note that you have to use definite integrals if you're going to start estimating things, or the arbitrary constant can ruin your day. And moreover, remember that the derivatives of $f$ are not necessarily nonnegative.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art Thanks, that is exactly what I am interested in. I guess this can be marked as a duplicate.