# Finding integral using derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives

In my calculus class, my professor mentioned how to find the integral of $ \ln (x) $ using IBP with $ v = 1 $ and $ u = \ln (x) $ which simplifies the problem as the derivative of $ \ln (x) $ is much easier to work out. I tried this for a general function $ f(x) $ and using repeated IBP obtained

$$ \begin{align} \displaystyle \int f(x) \; \text{d} x &= x f(x) - \displaystyle \int  x f'(x) \; \text{d} x \\ &= x f(x) - \dfrac{x^2}{2} f''(x) + \displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^2}{2} f'' (x) \; \text{d} x \\ &= \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} f^{(n)} (x) + (-1)^{N+1} \displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^{N+2}}{(n+2)!} f^{n+1} (x) \; \text{d} x \end{align} $$

Which seems to resemble the standard Taylor series for $ f(x) $ apart from the alternating signs? I'm also curious as to the interpretation of taking the infinite limit in this case and whether this has any use in evaluating or at least approximating it on a given interval.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141794/infinite-integration-by-parts

Answer (score 0):

In the special case that $f$ is analytic, we can express it as a power series about $x$:

$$ f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(t-x)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x) $$

Assuming $t=0$ is within the domain of convergence, integrating gives

$$ \int_0^x f(t)\, \mathrm{d}t = 
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^x\frac{(t-x)^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(x)  \, \mathrm{d}t$$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n  \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} f^{(n)}(x)$$

---

A similar argument can be made (with more general hypotheses) with a Taylor polynomial with remainder. IIRC, the argument you describe is one of the ways you can prove Taylor's theorem.